# Efficient custom datatype in Lua

Tags: types, lua, lua-userdata

I need a 2d vector-like data structure for use in Lua. So far I've found several solutions to this problem:

1. Classic solution of defining the datatype in pure Lua -- the disadvantage is that all operations on it (like addition) need to create a new datatype, set metatables, etc. x, y are stored as fields, and hence have fast access.
2. Classic full userdata solution on C-side -- it might be faster, still allows operators, operation code is C side, but still every operation needs to do a allocation of a new object. There is no possibilities of fields though, so one would need to do a custom __index/newindex function to simulate x and y what might be slow on Lua side.
3. Hybrid approach, where we define a Lua object but through C code, x and y would still be fields with simple access, but the functions would be coded in C, hence faster?

I did try the #1 approach and due to efficiency issues I plan to move to either #2 or #3, however I don't know which one would be more efficient.

On the far side there's also the possibility to hardcode the datatype in the compiler itself, but I don't think I'm ready yet for such drastic ideas :) (this isn't as crazy as it sounds, a 2d vector would nicely fit in the double size of a native Lua type).

Which of the two methods would be more efficient? Are there any pitfals I havn't thought about in those cases?

Comment: Do you **know** #1 is too slow?

Comment: @delnan, I know the two golden rules of optimizing Lua ;). Also, moving away from #1 is also dictated by other reasons (deployment of the structure from C level, and others).

Comment: Can you put your #1 implementation somewhere? Maybe it wasn't that optimal.

Comment: Lua Gems had a recipe for a numeric array and vector data type built in C and stored in `userdata`. The code wasn't *that* complex, with most of the complexity due to dealing with housekeeping, the ability to see rows and columns of a matrix as a vector without copying data, and so forth. That was Chapter 16, A Primer of Scientific Computing in Lua. Probably worth a look.

Answer (score 3):

Option #4: use [LuaJIT2](http://luajit.org/) with [FFI](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html)

See [related work](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-04/msg00852.html)

Comment: +1: wow, while it LuaJIT isn't something I can use (not all target architectures are supported) this is a very interesting link indeed, thanks!